# Sphinx: How to recover realtime index from backups?

Tags: sphinx

I already known how to implement a backup of realtime index by using `FLUSH RTINDEX` and compressing all involved files (.ram, .kill, .meta files) like below:

```
tar zcvf /backups/myrtbackup.tar.gz /sphinxdata/myrtindex.{*.sp*,ram,kill,meta} /sphinxdata/binlog.*
```

But there's question, if the system is crashed, or somehow we delete all data by mistake, **how could we recover from that backup?**

Answer (score 1):

Following a crash, or if the server goes and need to bring online a new one etc. Just restore those files to the data folder (while searchd is not running) and start searchd.

If search wont start you might have some luck not restoring the binlog, rather just the index files.

If you delete all the data, its not really going to help you. You can't 'roll back' and go back to a specific time.

In general the sphinx 'index' designed to be  created as an index over a real database somewhere else. Not as an authoritative database in itself.

Sphinxes "backups" are just not robust enough for you to be able to rely on them. Because sphinx indexes should be disposable, if they get currupted, just recreate them from the source data.

(the backups that you can do, are just 'hacks' that may help you get online **quicker** in case of disaster)

Comment: I see. I just simply rebuild the index from database... So after all, backing up realtime indexes isn't really necessary, is it? Could you tell me more specifically what we can do with the backups? Thank you!

Comment: No necessary no. I never bother. As say the main use for them, is the just to speed up recovery, if a server crashes, or goes offline.